# What is wrong with my intersection checking algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, math, intersection

I know there are many sites which explain how to check for an intersection of two lines, but I find it utterly boring to just copy and paste code for such a simple mathematical task. The more it frustrates me that I cannot get my code to work. I know questions with "What is wrong in my code?" are stupid, but I don't know what the hell is wrong with my mathematics / code, also my code is documented nicely (except of admittedly bad variable naming), so I guess there should be someone who is interested in the math behind it:

```
bool segment::checkforIntersection(QPointF a, QPointF b) { //line 1: a+bx, line 2: c+dx, note that a and c are called offset and bx and dx are called gradients in this code
QPointF bx = b-a;
double firstGradient = bx.y() / bx.x(); //gradient of line 1
//now we have to calculate the offset of line 1: we have b from a+bx. Since QPointF a is on that line, it is:
//a + b * a.x = a.y with a as free variable, which yields a = a.y - b*a.x.
//One could also use the second point b for this calculation.
double firstOffset = a.y() - firstGradient * a.x();
double secondGradient, secondOffset;
for (int i = 0; i < poscount-3; i++) { //we dont check with the last line, because that could be the same line, as the one that emited intersection checking
    QPointF c = pos[i];
    QPointF d = pos[i+1];
    QPointF dx = d-c;
    secondGradient = dx.y() / dx.x(); //same formula as above
    secondOffset = c.y() - secondGradient * c.x();
    //a+bx=c+dx <=> a-c = (d-b)x <=> (a-c)/(d-b) = x
    double x = (firstOffset - secondOffset) / (secondGradient - firstGradient);
    //we have to check, if those lines intersect with a x \in [a.x,b.x] and x \in [c.x,d.x]. If this is the case, we have a collision
    if (x >= a.x() && x <= b.x() && x >= c.x() && x <= d.x()) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

So what this does, it has 4 points a, b, c, d (line 1: a--b, line 2: c--d) (ignore the for loop) which have an absolute x and y value. First it calculates the gradient of the lines by calculating deltay/deltax. Then it calculates the offset by using the fact that point a (or c respectively) are on the lines. This way we transformed the 4 points into mathematical representation of these lines as equation a+bx, whereas a x of 0 means that we are at the first point (a / c) and a x of 1 means that we are on the second point (b/d). Next we calculate the intersection of those two lines (basic algebra). After that we check if the intersection's x value is valid. To my understanding this is all correct. Does anyone see the error?

This was empirically checked to be incorrect. The code does not give any false Positives (says there is an intersection, when there isn't), but it gives false Negatives (says there is no intersection, when there actually is). So when it says there is an Intersection it is correct, however if it says there is no intersection, you cannot always believe my algorithm.

Again, I checked online, but the algorithms are different (with some orientation tricks and something), I just wanted to come up with my own algorithm, I would be so glad if someone could help. :)

Edit: Here is a minimal reproducable not working example, this time without Qt but with C++ only:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
class Point {
private:
    double xval, yval;
public:
    // Constructor uses default arguments to allow calling with zero, one,
    // or two values.
    Point(double x = 0.0, double y = 0.0) {
        xval = x;
        yval = y;
    }

    // Extractors.
    double x() { return xval; }
    double y() { return yval; }

    Point sub(Point b)
    {
        return Point(xval - b.xval, yval - b.yval);
    }
};

bool checkforIntersection(Point a, Point b, Point c, Point d) { //line 1: a+bx, line 2: c+dx, note that a and c are called offset and bx and dx are called gradients in this code
    Point bx = b.sub(a);
    double firstGradient = bx.y() / bx.x(); //gradient of line 1
    //now we have to calculate the offset of line 1: we have b from a+bx. Since Point a is on that line, it is:
    //a + b * a.x = a.y with a as free variable, which yields a = a.y - b*a.x.
    //One could also use the second point b for this calculation.
    double firstOffset = a.y() - firstGradient * a.x();
    double secondGradient, secondOffset;
    Point dx = d.sub(c);
    secondGradient = dx.y() / dx.x(); //same formula as above
    secondOffset = c.y() - secondGradient * c.x();
    //a+bx=c+dx <=> a-c = (d-b)x <=> (a-c)/(d-b) = x
    double x = (firstOffset - secondOffset) / (secondGradient - firstGradient);
    //we have to check, if those lines intersect with a x \in [a.x,b.x] and x \in [c.x,d.x]. If this is the case, we have a collision
    if (x >= a.x() && x <= b.x() && x >= c.x() && x <= d.x()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    if (checkforIntersection(Point(310.374,835.171),Point(290.434,802.354), Point(333.847,807.232), Point(301.03,827.172)) == true) {
        cout << "These lines do intersect so I should be printed out\n";
    } else {
        cout << "The algorithm does not work, so instead I do get printed out\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So as example I took the points ~ (310,835) -- (290,802), and (333,807) -- (301,827). These lines do intersect:

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=.1cm,y=.1cm]
\draw (310,835) -- (290,802);
\draw (333,807) -- (301,827);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[Proof of intersection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xpIJ.png)
However when running the above C++ code, it says that they do not intersect

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: It's not like I didn't try to debug it by my own. I tried debugging, but after half a hour of having not a single clue what is wrong I eventually gave up. Maybe I just have misunderstood some math and that is the problem. What is the problem of asking after genuinely having tried solving it by your own?

Comment: `What is the problem of asking after genuinely having tried solving it by your own?` you are still missing the [mcve]

Comment: @m-s I indeed forgot an example of a point tupel where the algorithm does not work. I am truly sorry for the inconvenience. I edited the original post to match your request. Now all you have to do is copy the code and run g++ or clang++ on it. I hope now you are able to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(you may call me a pedant, but the terminology is important)

If you want to see if the line **segments** intersect, then rely on the parametric representation of your two segments, solve the system in the two parameters and see if both of the solution for both of the parameters falls into `[0,1]` range.

Parametric representation for segment [**`a`**, **`b`**], component-wise

> `{x, y}(t) = {(1-t)*ax+t*bx, (1-t)*ay+t*by}` with `t` in the `[0,1]` range

Quick check - at `t=0` you get **a**, at `t=1` you get **b**, the expression is linear in `t`, so there you have it.

So, your (a,b) (c,d) intersection problem becomes:

```
// for some t1 and t2, the x coordinate is the same
(1-t1)*ax+t*bx=(1-t2)*cx+t2*dx; 
(1-t1)*ay+t*by=(1-t2)*cy+t2*dy; // and so is the y coordinate
```

Solve the system in `t1` and `t2`. If `t1` is in the `[0,1]` range, then the intersection lies between `a` and `b`, the same goes for `t2` in respect with `c` and `d`.

It is left as an exercise for the reader the study of what effects will have on the system above the following conditions and what checks should be implemented for a robust algorithm:

1. segment degeneracy - coincident ends for one or both segments
2. collinear segments with non-void overlap. Particular case when there's a single point of overlap (necessary, that point will be one of the ends)
3. collinear segments with no overlap
4. parallel segments

Comment: I really like your idea of calculating it such that s, t \in [0,1]. You forgot to replace x in your second equation with y btw. Your equations are also not so simple to be solved for s or t. So instead I used the very similar equation a.x+s*(b.x-a.x)=c.x+t*(d.x-c.x) (the same with y for x). This equation has the same properties but I was able to solve for s much faster. So I just implemented it and ran the code and it works like a charm! Thanks for the good idea. Though this implementation is slower because it has to do much more calculations. However, it is working, and that is what I wanted

Comment: Tha for `y`. Regarding the alternate form... doh, I didn't say to take the equations and solve them *as they are* - I used that expression for the parametric repr of a line because it's easier to understand and remember it - a linear combination between ends with `t` and `1-t` weights.

Comment: @Magnus2552 "Though this implementation is slower because it has to do much more calculations." Keep in mind my saying: "nothing is slower than something that doesn't work. Nothing is more damaging than a buggy code producing errors at high speed".

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Early optimization is always a bad programming habit.

Answer (score 1):

> First it calculates the gradient of the lines by calculating deltay/deltax.

And what happens when deltax is very close to zero?

Look, what you are doing is exposing yourself to ill-conditioned situations - *always fear divisions and straight comparison with `0.0` when it comes to computational geometry*.

Alternative:

1. two lines will intersect if they are not parallel
2. two *distinct* lines will be parallel if their definition vectors will have a zero cross-product.

Cross-product of your `(a,b) x (c,d) = (ax-bx)*(cy-dy)-(ay-by)*(cx-dx)` - if this is close enough to zero, for all practical purposes there's no intersection between your lines (the intersection is so far away it doesn't matter).

Now, what remains to be said:

- there will need to be a "are those line distinct?" test before going into computing the cross-product. Even more, you will need to treat degenerate cases (one or both of the lines are reduced to a point by coincident ends - like `a==b` and/or `c==d`)
- the "close enough to zero" test is ambiguous if you don't normalize your definition vectors - imagine a 1 lightsecond-length vector defining the first line and a 1 parsec-length vector for the other (What test for 'proximity to zero' should you use in this case?)
   To normalize the two vectors, just apply a division ... <sup>(a division you say? I'm already shaking with fear)</sup> ... mmm.. I was saying to divide the resulted cross-product with `hypot(ax-bx, ay-by)*hypot(cx-dx,cy-dy)` (do you see why the degeneracy cases need to be treated in advance?)
- after the normalization, once again, what would be a good 'proximity to zero' test for the resulted cross-product? Well, I think I can go on with the analysis for another hour or so (e.g. how far the intersection would be when compared with the extent of your {a,b,c,d} polygon), but... since the cross-product of two unitary vectors (after normalization) is `sin(angle-between-versors)`, you may use your common sense and say 'if the angle is less that 1 degree, will this be good enough to consider the two lines parallel? No? What about 1 arcsecond?"